# Covering index not used in XML query

Tags: sql-server

Running `SQL Server 2014`. I have a stored procedure where I generate an `XML` using multiple selects. A simplified example below.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT ... FROM X WHERE ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('x'), TYPE),
    (SELECT ... FROM Y WHERE ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('y'), TYPE),
    (SELECT ... FROM Z WHERE ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('z'), TYPE),
    (SELECT IndexedColumn1, IndexedColumn2
    FROM W WHERE ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('w'), TYPE),
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT(root')
```

Looking at the I/O, I see that `IndexedColumn1` and `IndexedColumn2` do not show any `logical reads`. However, when I add a couple of more **simple** selects in the list, suddenly I see massive I/O for these indexed columns. Why?!

It seems that my non-clustered index is not considered when the query becomes bigger, even though this query is independent of the rest of the query. Should I ignore these increased `logical reads` or am I indeed doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan both before and after you add "a couple more simple selects"?

Comment: Dave.Gugg has a valid question. My simple guess would be that the original might be cached / optimized already.  Altering it causes the entire script to rebuild.

Comment: your description can not tell us to answer you. better to add some more like execution plan image with sample data and datastructure of table(s) (2 or 3 tables )

Comment: Also, the title indicates there is a covering index, yet nowhere in the text I see any mention about indexes. What index? What fields are 'covered' and how ? On what table(s) ?  It probably also would help if you gave at least some examples of those so-called simple queries. Even better, can you create a representative SqlFiddle of your situation?

Comment: I'm working on it. Trying to create a sample that demonstrates the problem.